# How to compare initialize values with run time stored values

Tags: java, selenium

I am working on a task in which I want to compare initialize values with run time stored values. The scenario is below:
First, I initialize the values provided by client
Then I display the values in output.

Problem:
When I compare them, I face a problem that I initialize
the values in double datatype and the values I store from run time in WebElement Datatype.
Please suggest me how to compare them.

Please watch the video to check how application working: https://www.loom.com/share/67dd0ec479ae4c0ba8d80643a0d52b8d

Screenshot: https://www.webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=7KWQfS4ad

Here is the Updated code:

```
//Initialize values
    double TP = 103.26;
    double TO = 0.00;
    double TDis = 3% (3.10);
    double SDis = 3.40;
    double EDis = 0;
    double Tax = 350.20;
    double NetAmount = 2350.04;
    
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "G:\\Autmation\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver ;
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    //Launche Browser
    System.out.println("*************Launch browser*************");
    driver.navigate().to("https://sell360d.allomate.solutions/");
    System.out.println("Title"  +driver.getTitle());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Url is launch");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    //Login into Application
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
      WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'exampleInputEmail_2')]")));
      username.sendKeys("username");
      WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'exampleInputpwd_2')]")));
      password.sendKeys("password");
      WebElement captcha = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/div/div[1]/app-login-component/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/re-captcha/div/div/iframe")));
      captcha.click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      WebElement login = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-login')]")));
      login.click();
      
      //Select Filters
      WebElement Order = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")));
      Order.click();
      
      WebElement countsale = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a")));
      countsale.click();
      
      WebElement Employee = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ng-select/div/div/div[2]/input"))));
      Employee.click();
      
      WebElement SelEmployee = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ng-select/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[2]/span"))));
      SelEmployee.click();
      
      WebElement Route = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-select/div/div/div[2]/input"))));
      Route.click();
      
      WebElement SelRoute = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/ng-select/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[2]/span"))));
      SelRoute.click();
      
      WebElement Reatailer = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ng-select/div/div/div[2]/input"))));
      Reatailer.click();
      
      WebElement SelReatailer = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath(
                "/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ng-select/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[2]/span"))));
      SelReatailer.click();
      
      //Add product
      WebElement addbtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@id,'productlist01')]")));
      addbtn.click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      
      WebElement addproduct = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/button")));
      addproduct.click();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      
      WebElement quantity = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[2]/div/div/app-orders-component/app-counter-sale/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")));
      quantity.sendKeys("20");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      
      WebElement confirm = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]")));
      confirm.click();
      
      WebElement cancel = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(@id,'pl-prod-close')]")));
      cancel.click();
      
      //Get values of slected product
      WebElement TP1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'103.26')]"));
      WebElement TO1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]"));
      WebElement TDis1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'3% (3.10)')]"));
      WebElement SDis1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]"));
      //List<WebElement> EDis1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'103.26')]"));
      WebElement Tax1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[9]"));
      WebElement NetAmount1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[10]"));
      
      
      //Display values in output
      System.out.println("Values" +TP1.getText() + " " + TO1.getText() + " " + TDis1.getText() + " " + SDis1.getText() + " "+ Tax1.getText() + " " + NetAmount1.getText());
      
      String TP2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'103.26')]")).getText();
      String TO2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]")).getText();
      String TDis2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'3% (3.10)')]")).getText();
      String SDis2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]")).getText();
      //List<WebElement> EDis1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'103.26')]"));
      String Tax2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[9]")).getText();
      String NetAmount2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/app-root[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/app-orders-component[1]/app-counter-sale[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[10]")).getText();
      
      System.out.println("Values After change datatype" + TP2 + " " + TO2 + " " + TDis2 + " " + SDis2 + " "+ Tax2 + " " + NetAmount2);
      
      String convertedTP = String.valueOf(TP);
      String convertedTO = String.valueOf(TO);
      String convertedTDis = String.valueOf(TDis);
      String convertedSDis = String.valueOf(SDis);
      String convertedTax = String.valueOf(Tax);
      String convertedNetAmount = String.valueOf(NetAmount);
      
      if (TP2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTP)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
      
      if (TO2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTO)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
      
      if (TDis2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTDis)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
      
      if (SDis2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedSDis)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
      
      if (Tax2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTax)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
      
      if (NetAmount2.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedNetAmount)) {
            System.out.println("Both values are same");
      } else {
            System.out.println("Both are not same");
      }
```

WebPage code:

```
<div class="col-12"><div class="row"><div class="_sa-customer"><div class="form-s2"><ng-select placeholder="Select Employee" class="formselect ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-searchable ng-select-clearable ng-valid ng-select-bottom ng-touched ng-dirty"><div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"><div class="ng-value-container"><div class="ng-placeholder">Select Employee</div><div class="ng-value"><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon left">×</span><span class="ng-value-label">Abdul Rehman Babar</span><!----></div><!----><!----><!----><!----><div role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-input" aria-expanded="false"><input aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="a426b25c1fd7" class=""></div></div><!----><span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span></span><!----><span class="ng-arrow-wrapper"><span class="ng-arrow"></span></span></div><!----></ng-select></div></div><div class="_sa-customer"><div class="form-s2"><ng-select placeholder="Select Route" class="formselect ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-searchable ng-select-clearable ng-valid ng-select-bottom ng-touched ng-dirty"><div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"><div class="ng-value-container"><div class="ng-placeholder">Select Route</div><div class="ng-value"><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon left">×</span><span class="ng-value-label">Harbanspura (A) </span><!----></div><!----><!----><!----><!----><div role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-input" aria-expanded="false"><input aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="a13cf9ea6398" class=""></div></div><!----><span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span></span><!----><span class="ng-arrow-wrapper"><span class="ng-arrow"></span></span></div><!----></ng-select></div></div><div class="_sa-customer"><div class="form-s2"><ng-select placeholder="Select Retailer" class="formselect ng-select ng-select-single ng-select-searchable ng-select-clearable ng-valid ng-select-bottom ng-touched ng-dirty"><div class="ng-select-container ng-has-value"><div class="ng-value-container"><div class="ng-placeholder">Select Retailer</div><div class="ng-value"><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-value-icon left">×</span><span class="ng-value-label"> koita Chapman dry fruits shop</span><!----></div><!----><!----><!----><!----><div role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="ng-input" aria-expanded="false"><input aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="afd630aaf2e3" class=""></div></div><!----><span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span></span><!----><span class="ng-arrow-wrapper"><span class="ng-arrow"></span></span></div><!----></ng-select></div></div><button id="productlist01" class="btn btn-primary ml-15">Add Product</button></div><div class="_cut-detail"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><strong>Retailer Name: &nbsp; </strong> koita Chapman dry fruits shop </div><div class="col-md-6"><strong>Channel Type: &nbsp; </strong> Bakery</div><div class="col-md-6"><strong>Location: &nbsp; </strong> harbanspura service road</div><div class="col-md-6"><strong>Territory: &nbsp; </strong> LHR-TER-001</div></div></div><div class="_add-product"><div class="row AP_heading"><div class="addItemCell PL-5">Product Name</div><div class="addItemCell unit-w">Unit</div><div class="addItemCell2">QTY.</div><div class="addItemCell2">T.P</div><div class="addItemCell2">T.O </div><div class="addItemCell2">T. Dis. (%)</div><div class="addItemCell2">S. Disc.</div><div class="addItemCell2">E. Disc.</div><div class="addItemCell2">Tax</div><div class="addItemCell3">Net Amount</div></div><div class="row _row-product"><a href="#" class="dd-handle dd3-handle swap-div"></a><div class="col-12 p-0"><div class="addItemCell PL-5"><div class="_emp-sele _product-name"> B.B. Chilli Chips Rs10 (12X24) </div></div><div class="addItemCell unit-w"><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"> Box </div></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"><input type="text" placeholder="0" class="addItemCell2_input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" style="font-size: 13px;"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25">103.26</div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25">0.00 </div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25">3% (3.10) </div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25">3.20</div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"><input type="text" placeholder="0" class="addItemCell2_input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" style="font-size: 13px;"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25">350.20 </div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">2,350.24 </div><a title="Delete" class="btn _order-del"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div></div><!----><!----><div class="row _totalBar _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5">Total Items</div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w">1</div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Gross Amount:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">2,065.20</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Trade Offer:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">0.00</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Trade Discount:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">61.96</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Special Discount:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">3.20</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Extra Discount:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">0.00</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t">Tax:</div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25">350.20</div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t"><strong>Total Amount Due:</strong></div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25" style="font-size: 18px; color: #0038ba;"> 2,350.24 </div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t"><strong>Cash:</strong></div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25" style="font-size: 18px; color: #0038ba;"> 2,350.24 </div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t"><strong>Cheque Payment:</strong></div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25" style="font-size: 18px; color: #0038ba;"> 0.00 </div></div><div class="row _totalBar2"><div class="addItemCell _h25 PL-5"></div><div class="addItemCell _h25 unit-w"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25"></div><div class="addItemCell2 _h25 width-t"><strong>Credited Amount:</strong></div><div class="addItemCell3 _h25" style="font-size: 18px; color: #0038ba;"> 0.00 </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: @cruisepandey : ScreenShot: webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=mUdY6K17d Please check screenshot I am facing problem, only first output is working correctly. All other values are same, but it displays values are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert `web element` to `String` by using `.getText`

```
String TP1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'103.26')]")).getText();
```

Now you have a string `TP1` and a `double TP`. So you can first convert double to String like this :

```
String convertedTP = String.valueOf(TP);
```

and then now we have `TP1` and `convertedTP` in a string. There are multiple ways to verify if they are equal or not.

Something like this :

```
TP1.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTP);
```

and `print` if they are `equal or not.`

```
if (TP1.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTP))
    System.out.println("Both values are same");
else
    System.out.println("Both are not same");
```

Comment: ScreenShot:  https://www.webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=mUdY6K17d    Please check screenshot I am facing problem, only first output is working correctly. All other values are same, but it displays values are not same

Comment: Are you sure you have converted all the values ? The above answer is just to explain how to convert so I did convert the first one not all, you have to convert all like above

Comment: Yes I'm converting all types.

Comment: Can you show me ? Please update your post with new changes

Comment: Please check screen shot: https://www.webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=5gHiewpqX

Comment: okay you will have to print them as well before calling any if conditions. You should print all the converted ones. and share the output with me. There can be trailing spaces as well, try to trim the string before comparison. Something like this `if (TP1.equalsIgnoreCase(convertedTP.trim()))`

Comment: Here is the output of all converted ones: https://www.webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=mBnZU0x_Q

Comment: Can you mail me all the code that you've with creds, I can look into it very efficiently .

Comment: May be double should not have those parenthesis

Comment: Actually, my client not allowed me to share the credential with anyone. Are you have any other way to check this problem. Please don't mind

Comment: I have a doubt at this `double TDis = 3% (3.10);` why do you have a double like this ? Also I do not see this in UI.

Comment: Please check the screenshot to see UI: https://www.webpagescreenshot.info/#v2=6Xz5c4Efj

Comment: then when you are defining this like in double ? It should be string.

Answer (score 0):

In your case TP.getText() is a String, so you can convert String to Double using :

```
 Double tpd = Double.parseDouble(TP.getText());
```

or

```
 Double tpd = Double.valueOf(TP.getText());
```

or

```
  Double tpd = new Double(TP.getText());
```

then you can compare it :

```
     if(TP=tpd){
         ...
     }
```